# drscheme c# adapter

Tags: c#, scheme, adapter, racket

Hi guys i need to integrate drscheme into my c# code for my assignment but i could find any luck on the web. Can anyone help me ? I tried ironscheme but got the following error.

> The type or namespace name 'Dynamic' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Integration\Integration\Form1.cs 2 14 Integration

Have tried googling the error message but could find any related stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Methinks you need to be more specific about what you mean by "integrat[ing] drscheme into my c# code for my assignment".  FWIW, calling DrScheme code from C# and calling C# code from DrScheme are both going to be extraordinarily difficult.

Answer (score 0):

DrScheme and IronScheme are 2 different and independent implementations of Scheme.

Your error message is due to trying to use .NET 4 assemblies that are not referenced.

Make sure you are using C# 4 and .NET 4 (iow VS 2010) and that the System.Dyamic assembly is referenced.

Comment: do i have to use .Net 4 for this? is there any other adapters i can use for drscheme to c# with .NET 3.5

Comment: @alan: Sorry, I cant help you for DrScheme.